# finding date and time of last 5 days

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find out the date and time of last 5 days from the database,the data inserted into the table is in the form of date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
Now when i try retrieving it the values do not show up until the time from the table is removed
My Query is :

```
 SELECT  Key,DATE_FORMAT(lastUpdated, '%D %M %Y')
 FROM    table
 WHERE   lastUpdated Between NOW() - INTERVAL 5 DAY AND NOW()
 ORDER BY Key DESC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to just compare the DATE() of the lastUpdated

```
 SELECT  Key,DATE_FORMAT(lastUpdated, '%D %M %Y')
 FROM    table
 WHERE   DATE(lastUpdated) Between NOW() - INTERVAL 5 DAY AND NOW()
 ORDER BY Key DESC;
```